# Why Camel Spring 2.20.2 results in NIST vulnerabilities CVE-2016-9878 and CVE-2017-5929

Tags: java, apache-camel

When I add Camel spring latest version (2.20.2) I am getting NIST vulnerabilities CVE-2016-9878 and CVE-2017-5929.  As per the vulnerabilities the packages org.springframework_spring version 2.5.6 and ch.qos.logback_logback-core 0.9.29
are leading to vulnerabilities.  But actually camel-spring 2.20.2 don't have packages org.springframework_spring version 2.5.6 and ch.qos.logback_logback-core 0.9.29 in it's transitive dependencies.  How to resolve this issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: NIST links for the vulnerabiliites https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2016-9878 and https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-5929